# REGEX to parse words from cell in googlesheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Hoping somebody can help me with the syntax.

Cell `A1` contains the following value:

```
Content Type: Pitch Decks; Region: North America; Content Type: Data Sheet;
```

I'm trying to create a formula that parses the values between the words `"Content Type: "` and the semicolon that follows.

So in `B1`, the expected result of the formula should be:

```
Pitch Decks
Data Sheet
```

(Yes, with `char(10)` separating the values in `B1`)

I've tried a number of different combinations of `REGEXEXTRACT`, for example:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A11,"Content Type: ([\w\/\s]*);?")
```

..only returns:

```
Pitch Decks
```

I've read that global modifiers are not supported in Google Sheets. That formula works when I add a global modifier in a regex test harness, but not when used within Google Sheets itself.

Comment: This would be very easy with substitution and a Lookahead but Google Sheets doesn't seem to support Lookaheads either. You'd probably have to combine regex with other Google Sheets functions to find and join the matches. Unfortunately, I'm not really experienced with Google Sheets. Hopefully, someone else is going to help you. Good question though; upvoted.

Comment: Yes.. this has had me quite baffled for 24 hours. I've read 20 different stackoverflow posts on the matter of parsing and regex .. tried 'em.. but to no avail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would be easy with substitution and a Lookahead but turns out Google Sheets doesn't support Lookaheads either. After some research, I came up with the following solution:

```
=join(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Content Type: )([^;]+)","$1($2)")))
```

This will find all the strings that come after "Content Type: " and until the next semicolon or the end of the string. Then, it will join them using a LineFeed. If you want to join using a different character, you may replace `CHAR(10)` with `","`, for example, to join with a comma.

**Output:**

```
Pitch Decks
Data Sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1:A, ";"), "Content Type")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A, ";"), ": (.+)"), ), " ", "♥"))
 ,,9^9))), " ", CHAR(10)), "♥", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the use of the special characters .. but the solution from 
41686d6564 above did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!